# External JavaScript File not working when included in body of HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

This is my external javascript file - current-time.js:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var hours       = currentDate.getHours();
var minutes     = currentDate.getMinutes();
```

Now the above code works when i type it directly into my html file. But does not work when i include it as an external file.
This is my HTML file where i am including my external js file- Display-time.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

    <p id ="container"></p>

    <script src="current-time.js">

    var display = document.getElementById("container");
    display.innerHTML = hours+ ":" +minutes;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help .As i have tried out numerous ways by changing place of my external js file, tried changing the element from p to div and lots of other things.But this just does not work.

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Comment: You can't have contents in the same `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute. Put them in different tags.

Comment: Try to put separate <script> for external file

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!!! I have put the content in another <script> tag and it is working perfectly fine.